# Strategy for second remote repo with truncated history

Tags: git

I have my application's repository, however I want to have a second repo where the commits are more curated based on releases.

Essentially I don't want this repo to have the full commit history.  I just want to push a squashed commit per release. Is there a way to do this easily, or does it require creating multiple git repos and managing them separately?

Bonus points if I can commit extra code into this repo (ex. the vendor folder).  Extra bonus points if I can commit the contents of submodules but not as submodules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I want to do is detailed here https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/our-git-workflow/

By creating a branch for my second repo and using `git merge --squash <release branch name>` I can have a private repo and a public one.